# Presentation Without Mirroring on MacBookPro

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

I know this is similar to other questions, but not quite. I'm used to Windows and now I have a MacBookPro at school. In Windows I can show a slide from a presentation while working on another application on my laptop. I know it interferes with the slideshow, but I really just want to show that one slide to my class. I can do that with Windows, however, on the MacBookPro I use at school, after clicking off mirroring and going to the slideshow I immediately get the presenter's view so I can't do anything else but the presentation. I am clicking on View Slideshow not clicking on View Presenter's Tools. The screen has the slide and my desktop switches to presenter's view. Am I missing something or will my Mac not allow anything else but the presentation to work at the same time? As I said, I went to settings > display and turned off mirroring.

Comment: What presentation software and what OS version?

Comment: Which MS Office Version do u use? Perhaps this Topic helps http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16769/how-to-keep-powerpoint-from-mirroring-my-monitors-when-switching-apps ?

Comment: I just tested it in PP2011 on Mavericks and it does not appear that there is any mode which will allow you to do what you want to do. The post Sidasa points to is a good one and is also my experience.